# How to make a secure nginx-proxy to point different paths in single server?

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to use **letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion** in my Docker instance.
After some reading I still cannot find solution for my schema:

```
  HOST => DOCKER
   /        |
 (vps)      |
        (containers)
            - nginx-proxy
            - letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

            - portainer [to manage self-hosted docker]
                https://projects.domain.com:4488
            - jenkins [to manage projects from github]
                https://projects.domain.com:5533

            - projects home [static website]
                https://projects.domain.com
            - project #1
                https://projects.domain.com/project-1
            - project #2
                https://projects.domain.com/project-2
```

Assuming I know how to manage multiple **subdomains** (each for container) I miss how (and where) specify **/path** for projects.

Where to start if I want to route **all** traffic throught SSL (excluding script for certificate renewal) and manage projects with Jenkins? Is it a good idea to wrap it in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "location /" tag with proxy_pass and subfilters? 
For example:

```
server {
    server_name jenkins.domain.com;
    listen 80 ;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name jenkins.domain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/sslcertificate.crt
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sslkey.key;


    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding “”;
    sub_filter_types ‘text/html’;
    sub_filter_types ‘text/css’;
    sub_filter ‘http://jenkins.domain.com‘ ‘https://$host';
    sub_filter_once off;

server {
    server_name projects.domain.com;
    listen 80 ;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

location /project-1/{
proxy_pass http://jenkins.domain.com:4488/project-1/;
    }
}
```